# Acumatica Best way to get Sum of all custom grid column values?

Tags: acumatica

Im trying to set the value of the field below to the sum of all the costs in the grid. 
[image]

Ive tried using PXFormula in the DAC

```
[PXParent ( typeof(Select<ProjectEntry_Extension.atcProjectLinesTable,Where<ProjectEntry_Extension.atcProjectLinesTable.contractID,
Equal<Current<Contract.contractID>>>>))]
[PXFormula(null, typeof(SumCalc<ProjectEntry_Extension.atcProjectLinesTable.unPrice>))]
[PXUIField(DisplayName="Fixture Estimated Total")]
```

Also tried using

```
cache.SetValueExt<ContractExt.usrFixtureTotals>(row.UnPrice, null);
```

In the RowUpdated event in the BLC

Comment: Please update your question according to stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - both this thread and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41334974/acumatica-programmatically-getting-sum-of-values-from-table/41335793?noredirect=1#comment69878743_41335793 ask pretty much same thing providing no detail information about the task itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my point, the best way to achieve this will be PXFormula and some header DAC, where results will be stored.

E.g. you'll have some DAC 'Header' with only field called 'Sum'. This field can be invisible on the screen.
After that you put PXFormula on the lines to calculate 'Sum'.
After that you set value to the new line on RowInserted like that:

```
protected virtual void RowInserted(PXCache sender, PXRowInsertedEventArgs e)
{
    SomeType line = (SomeType)e.Row;
    line.Value=Header.Current.Sum;
}
```

Comment: I have the header DAC setup and my PXFormula is below but its not working. I read in anonther post that extensions dont work with PXFormula is that true? If so what other techniques would work to calculate a total?
[PXFormula(null, typeof(SumCalc<ProjectEntry_Extension.atcProjectLinesTable.unPrice>))]